# Return keys sorted by value in dictionary of arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting, dictionary

I am no expert in python, so this may be easily solvable and/or duplicate.

I have a dictionary of arrays like so:

```
mydict = {
  "Anna": [10, 25, 6],
  "Bob": [15, 21, 9],
  "Carl": [17, 28, 3]
     }
```

What would be the easiest way to return a list of keys sorted based on one of the values in the array?
Say I wanted to sort them based on the second value of the array (`25, 21, 28`) so as to get a list in this order `["Bob", "Anna", "Carl"]`

My dictionary is tens of thousands, possibly millions, of entries, so efficiency is quite important.

Comment: Did you check https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a list of easily sortable data structures like `(25, 'Anna')`, sort that, then get rid of the superfluous value. As a one-liner:

```
[i[1] for i in sorted((v[1], k) for k, v in mydict.items())]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the obvious key function:

```
sorted(mydict, key=lambda k: mydict[k][1])
```